# How to detect when Android device has resumed from deep sleep?

Tags: android, multicast, power-management

I have  theory that my IGMP multicast sockets stop working after a device resumes from deep sleep (presumably because IGMP group membership times out). Is there a way to detect whether a device has gone to sleep (other than tracking the skew between upTimeMillis() and the current wall clock time)?  Note that I'm interested specifically in whether the CPU has gone to sleep, not whether the screen has gone to sleep. Yes I have a multicast lock. But I'd like to release the partial wakelock and/or the wifi lock.